# Evaluate action of $f(\frac{d}{dx})$ using the Fourier/Laplace transform

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-operators, fourier-transform, pseudo-differential-operators, laplace-transform

Consider a function $f(x)$ that is numerically defined in $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ interval (assume $N$ samples). I am trying to compute the action of $f(d/dx)$ on a function $g(x)$ using the Fourier transform as follows:

\begin{equation}
f(d/dx) g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(i\omega)\mathcal{G}(\omega)e^{i\omega x}dw,
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{G}$ is the Fourier transform of $g(x)$. Say for instance, if $f(x)=x$, the above integral leads to $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$ as expected. I am however stuck in calculating $f(i\omega)$ when $f$ is known numerically.

**Question**: How to evaluate $f(i\omega)$ given $N$ available samples?

Thank you for your help.

**Update:** It is suggested in the comment section to fit a polynomial through the data to have an analytic expression for $f(x)$. The problem that I faced with this approach is that the polynomial explods when $\omega$ gets large and I couldnot get anything meaningful from the integration above.

Comment: you will need to know the function on the imaginary axis, so there is some ambiguity if you only know the function on the real axis; you could fit a polynomial through your data and then extend the function analytically to the complex plane.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Carlo. I have updated the question above.

Comment: Added the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/729687/332828 as well.